Nginx Issue while deploying dockerized laravel to Digital Ocean
I am deploying Containerized Laravel to Digital Ocean using the bitbucket pipeline. I am pushing the PHP image to the docker hub and pulling it from there. Everything goes right but in the end, nginx starts to fail. However, I have tried to fix it but still have no luck. However, it works fine locally. I am sharing the code that I have used for server deployment. Any help will be appreciated.
Nginx Code
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server_tokens off;
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types application/json;
    gzip_min_length 1000;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

Default.conf code
server {
  listen 80;
  index index.php index.html;
  root /var/www/public;

  client_max_body_size 100M; # 413 Request Entity Too Large

  location / {
    root /var/www/public;
    index  index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    send_timeout 3600;
    proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
    proxy_read_timeout    3600;
    proxy_send_timeout    3600;
  }
}

Bitbucket Pipeline
image: atlassian/default-image:latest

pipelines:
  default:
        - step:
            name: Build and Push to Docker Hub
            services:
              - docker
            script:
              - docker login -u $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
              - docker build -t $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME/php-app:latest -f docker/php/Dockerfile .
              - docker push $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME/php-app:latest
        - step:
            name: Deploy to DigitalOcean
            deployment: production
            script:
              - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.4.3
                variables:
                  SSH_USER: $DO_SSH_USER
                  SERVER: $DO_SERVER
                  COMMAND: |
                    docker login -u $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
                    docker pull $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME/php-app:latest
                    docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml down &&
                    docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d

This is my server docker-compose-dev.yml script
services:
  php:
    image: sundarban123/php-app
    ports:
      - 5173:5173
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www:cached
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
      - .docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - .docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
  db:
    image: mysql:8.1
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - .docker/db/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - .docker/logs:/var/log/mysql
      - .docker/db/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
      - .docker/db/sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ****
      MYSQL_USER: *****
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: *****

My folder structure

Error from Pipeline

Actual Error Message
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/tmp/docker/nginx/nginx.conf" to $DO_SSH_USERfs at "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf": mount /tmp/docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf (via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0x5000: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
Connection to $DO_SERVER closed.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you
